# how to let systemd automatically mount the keydev?

Tags: linux, systemd, luks

in `/etc/crypttab` I have entry:

```
luks_part UUID=<uuid> /keyfile:LABEL=keydev luks
```

From the manual it seems the systemd should automatically find the partition which match the label and then automatically mount it and pass the keyfile to cryptsetup. But it does not mount the usb stick which has a vfat file system on it. I also added a hook in initramfs which manually add vfat module.

What did I do wrong here?

Comment: Are you trying to make this happen in the initramfs or in the booted system?

Comment: If it can work in initramfs it will be nicer. But if it doesn't it is still OK. Since the part I want to mount is after the initramfs state, my root partition is not encrypted.

Comment: And I am so confused about debain/ubuntu crypttab handling why there are 2 specification for that? one is systemd-cryptsetup one is debian specified. Can I switch to systemd only style? In arch I can pass kernel parameters like rd.lusk to modify the behavior. However, in debain/ubuntu it does not respect that even the rd.lusk parameters are in their man page.

Comment: Crypttab handling used to vary between distros, Arch had its own code, Debian had its own. When systemd is in use, it'll always use its own crypttab format, but if a non-systemd initramfs is being used then yes it'll be different. (Initramfs parameters -- even more so. `rd.*` parameters are a systemd convention, and other non-systemd initramfs builds won't automatically recognize them. I think even Arch's initramfs won't by default.)

Comment: What units are generated in `/run/systemd/generator*` after you add this crypttab entry and run `systemctl daemon-reload`? Is this key device actually a normal partition that will be in fstab and will stay mounted for general use, or is it dedicated to just this key file?